# Importing Jersey archive lib in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jersey

I am trying to import Jersey archive lib into my project in eclipse. According to the reference slides that I am using, I see the Jersey jar files imported under WEB-INF > Lib but when I write a class to import the jersey classes (`import javax.ws.rs.*;`) eclipse tells me that the import `javax.ws` cannot be resolved.

[image]

Comment: The `lib` should be _directly_ in the `WEB-INF`. You have it in the `jersey-archive` folder